# JQX Notification Widget showing multiple messages

Tags: jquery, jqxwidgets

Currently I am using jqx notification widget where a click on a button below code executes. But the problem is it displays multiple messages when we click on a button. I want to restrict it to single notification when we click on that button. Once it fades and the user clicks on that button it should display that message.

```
$('#dialog').after("<div id = 'jqxNotification' style='display: none;'>Saved Successfully.</div>");
$("#jqxNotification").jqxNotification({ width: 250, position: "top-right", opacity: 0.9,
        autoOpen: true, animationOpenDelay: 800, autoClose: true, template: "success"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some tips

There's no any setting for to do this, but what you can do is 
before open showing notification hide all previous all notification by property `.jqxNotification("closeAll")`

```
function showMessage() {
   $("#jqxNotification").jqxNotification("closeAll");
   $('#dialog').after("<div id = 'jqxNotification' style='display: none;'>Saved Successfully.</div>");

   $("#jqxNotification").jqxNotification({ width: 250, position: "top-right", opacity: 0.9,
        autoOpen: true, animationOpenDelay: 800, autoClose: true, template: "success"
   });
}

showMessage()
setTimeout(showMessage,1000);
```